# What is $(\mathbb R^3)^*$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Can anyone please tell me what is $(\mathbb R^3)^*$  in the following question ?

[image]

Comment: A vector in $(\mathbb{R}^3)^*$ is a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$. The general example of this thing takes the form $f(x_1, x_2, x_3) = ax_1 + b x_2 + c x_3$ for some tuple $(a,b,c)$. They're often written as row vectors, if you are familiar with vector algebra.

Comment: @leslietownes did you mean row vectors?

Comment: I think it is the dual vector space of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: @AlekosRobotis Yes and soon enough to edit it in time! Thanks.

Comment: If every elements of $(\mathbb R^3)^*$ is a function then why it is called vector ?@leslietownes

Comment: @cmi Any element of a vector space can be called a vector.

Comment: Null space of any vector of $(\mathbb R^3)^*$ is   of dimension $2$. Then how the given plane will be a null space of that vector ?@KevinArlin

Comment: Maybe the terminology and notation is just throwing you off.  If it isn't helpful to thinking in terms of "planes through the origin" (for many people it might not be), or $(\mathbb{R}^3)^*$, it isn't necessary to use that terminology or notation to solve the problem. You could cross out the phrases "the plane" and "through the origin in $\mathbb{R}^3$" entirely from the statement of the problem, and replace "vector in $(\mathbb{R}^3)^*$" with "linear map from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}$" (this is just applying the definition of that symbol), and it's exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

$(\Bbb R^3)^\ast$ is the *dual* of $\Bbb R^3$: the vector space of all linear maps $\Bbb R^3 \to R$. So a "vector" (generic term for an element of a vector space) in this dual is a linear map from $\Bbb R^3$ to $\Bbb R$.

To show this fact, extend $\{u,v\}$ to a basis $\{u,v,w\}$ of $\Bbb R^3$ and define
$f: \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R$ by
$f(x_1 u + x_2 v + x_3 w) = x_3$ and check it is linear. What is its null space?

Comment: $\{u , v\}$  is a linearly dependent set. How $\{u , v , w\}$  will be a basis of $\mathbb R^3$.@Henno Brandsma

Comment: @cmi you can extend any linearly independent subset to a basis for the whole space. So such a $w$ exists.

Comment: Yes that is true. Can you edit your answer ?@Henno Brandsma

Comment: @cmi there is nothing to edit. It states the fact correctly.

Comment: If $\{u, v\}$  is a linearly dependent set , then so is  $\{u , v , w\}$. How it will be basis of $\mathbb R^3$  ? @Henno Brandsma

Comment: @cmi I just say (correctly) that there *is* a choice of $w$ that will make it a basis. Ading $w=u+v$ will make it dependent so your assertion is wrong.

Comment: You may not have read the question or  You did not get my question.@Henno Brandsma

Comment: @cmi I did read and get your question. Did you read my answer? I defined $f \in (\Bbb R^3)^\ast$ and the null space is exactly the plane from the question; this is a good hint how to solve the question, if you think about it.

Comment: How $\{u , v , w\}$  is a basis when it is given that $\{u , v\}$  is a dependent set ?@Henno Brandsma

Comment: It's a mistake in the exercise. It should obviously say **independent**.

Comment: Null space of any vector in $(\mathbb R^3)^*$  will be of two dimension. Then how the subspace generated by the dependent set of vectors $\{u , v\}$ is becoming the null space. @Henno Brandsma

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120121/discussion-between-henno-brandsma-and-cmi).

Comment: I am trying to say this from the beginning. @Henno Brandsma